# Portable printf format specifier for 64 bit hexadecimal?

Tags: c, printf

What printf format specifier can I use to print a 64 bit unsigned integer in hexadecimal notation across 32/64 bit and Windows/POSIX? The closest I've seen is `%llX` but I'm not sure that is portable enough. Answers that ignore older compilers (e.g. Visual Studio 2010) are acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `PRIx64` macro in [`<inttypes.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) is what you're looking for.

It's a string token, so you can use it as:
`fprintf(stdout, "answer = %"PRIx64"\n", val);`

Since you specify `%llX`, you probably want uppercase; use: `PRIX64`

Comment: That was it. The inttypes reference I was looking at only had PRIx macros up to 32 bits for some reason.

Comment: `printf("answer = %#018"PRIx64"\n", val)` to print leading zeros

Answer (score 1):

You can use macros `PRIx64` or `PRIX64 (for  unsigned uppercase hexadecimal integer )` defined in header `<inttypes.h>`.